# Backup TO URL WITH NOINIT fails because file already exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

There's a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461195/sql-server-backup-to-url-fails-if-file-exists) but I cannot work out the solution because the circumstances are slightly different, so please bear with me; I've been wresting with the official [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) docs all day.

My goal is to have one backup file per database per day, with 15 minute recovery objective.  I am scheduling agent jobs as follows:

1. Once a day at 00:00, create a full backup of each database specified
2. Every 15 minutes, create a transaction log backup of each database specified

Ignoring all the code to iterate through the required databases, this is the core logic of part 1 above:

```
    DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50) = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM #DbsToBackup WHERE (Id = @current));
    DECLARE @dbNameAndDate nvarchar(200) = @dateString + '_' + @dbName;
    DECLARE @dbSpecificContainerUrl  nvarchar(MAX) = @containerUrl + @dbNameAndDate + '.bak';
    DECLARE @verifyError nvarchar(200) = N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ' + @dbName + ' not found.';

    BACKUP DATABASE @dbName 
         TO URL = @dbSpecificContainerUrl 
         WITH CREDENTIAL = @containerCredential
        ,NOINIT
        ,NAME = @dbNameAndDate
        ,COMPRESSION
        ,CHECKSUM
        ;
```

Then, the transaction log backup logic is as follows (same steps for grabbing the database name, date strings, etc.:

```
    BACKUP LOG @dbName 
         TO URL = @dbSpecificContainerUrl 
         WITH CREDENTIAL = @containerCredential
        ,NOINIT
        ,NAME = @dbNameAndDate
        ,SKIP
        ,COMPRESSION
        ,CHECKSUM
    ;
```

Part 1 works on the first attempt, but part 2 (and any subsequent re-run of part 1) immediately fails with this:

> A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "https://.....Test.bak:"
> The file https://....Test.bak exists on the remote endpoint, and WITH
> FORMAT was not specified.  Backup cannot proceed..  [SQLSTATE 42000]
> (Error 3271)  BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.  The step failed.

I get that the .bak file is already there, but I thought that `NOINIT` forced an append which would add the transaction log data into the existing .bak file.

I'm probably missing something simple but can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15), it seems that is not supported.

> Appending to existing backup blobs is not supported. Backups to an
> existing blob can only be overwritten by using the WITH FORMAT option.
> However, when using file-snapshot backups (using the WITH
> FILE_SNAPSHOT argument), the WITH FORMAT argument is not permitted to
> avoid leaving orphaned file-snapshots that were created with the
> original file-snapshot backup.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `@dbSpecificContainerUrl` contains the `@dateString` (preferably in ISO 8610 format) so each log backup gets its own file.

eg

```
set @dateString = FORMAT(GetUtcDate(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

Comment: As per the question, the goal is to have one backup file per database per day.  I'm trying to minimise have so many files.

Comment: That's not possible with backup to Azure Blob Storage, as you can't append new backups to a single file.  You're free to put the log backups in a "subfolder" by seperating the day and time by '/'.  eg `/backups/mydb/20210514/tlog/tlog-02:15:00.bak`